# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils' has no attribute 'to_categorical'

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the code below in my Jupyter Notebook.
I get:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils' has no
> attribute 'to_categorical'

This is code from Kaggle tutorial. I have installed Keras and Tensorflow.

```
 import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from tensorflow.python import keras
    from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout  

      img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
    num_classes = 10
    
    def data_prep(raw):
        out_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(raw.label, num_classes)
    
        num_images = raw.shape[0]
        x_as_array = raw.values[:,1:]
        x_shaped_array = x_as_array.reshape(num_images, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        out_x = x_shaped_array / 255
        return out_x, out_y
    
    raw_data = pd.read_csv('trainMNIST.csv')
    
    x, y = data_prep(raw_data)
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x, y,
              batch_size=128,
              epochs=2,
              validation_split = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 8):

Newer versions of keras==2.4.0 and tensorflow==2.3.0 would work as follows.

Import:

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
```

or

```
from keras import utils as np_utils
```

and then replace `keras.utils.to_categorical` with

```
keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical
```

Answer (score 2):

Include this in your code

`from tensorflow import keras`

in place of

`from tensorflow.python import keras`

Answer (score 1):

Use keras>=2.2 and tensorflow >=1.14 to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As it already has been said, **`to_categorical()`** is function. It in keras for tensorflow 2.x can be imported this way:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

then used like this:

```
digit=6
x=to_categorical(digit, 10)
print(x)
```

it will print

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Where 10 is the number of classes, the input values range is [0;number_of_classes-1]. The output is activated (1) or not active (0) position.

Answer (score 1):

As of tensorflow version 2.9.2, the correct import is:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```